# A reference to the object of the class with dynamically allocated memory and destructor

Tags: c++, oop, reference, destructor, dynamic-memory-allocation

Let's assume I have three classes:

```
class A{
};

class B{
   int S;
   A* arr;
   B(int s):S(s){
      arr = new A[S];
   }
   ~B(){
   delete [] arr;    
   }
};

class C{
   B& b;
   C(B& b): b(b){}
};
```

Should I define explicitly a destructor in class C? What would it look like?

Comment: This is something that you need to figure out yourself, based on how the rest of your application code uses these classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I define explicitly a destructor in class C?

To answer that question, you must know what your class does. Is the purpose of the class to manage allocated memory? Then, yes you probably need a destructor. Is the purpose to refer to an object managed by something else? Then why would you need a destructor? If you don't know what a destructor should do, then you quite often do not need one.

You should never use owning references, so there should be little reason for `C` to have a destructor, or it has to be changed drastically.

You also should not use owning bare pointers, so class `B` should also be changed. Easiest solution is to replace it with `std::vector`.

Comment: Thank you, it is very simplified version of my code. The class C isn't responsible for memory management, it only uses the array from class B.

Comment: @ZvR Ok. What do you think the destructor should do?

Comment: I was thinking about deleting an array from class B just after using it in class C. I wasn't sure If I wait for the B's destructor it won't cause some memory error.

Comment: @ZvR `B`'s array is deleted by `B`'s destructor. Therefore `B` "owns" the memory. If you attempt to delete memory in `C`'s destructor that `C` doesn't own, you'll end up attempting to deleting it twice, which causes the program's behaviour to be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need a destructor for `C`, but you do need a copy-constructor (as well as a move-constructor, copy-assignment operator and move-assignment operator) for class `B` if you want to correctly implement copy-semantics. As it is now if you were to make a copy of an object of class `B`, you would have to objects pointing to the same array - when the objects are destructed you would get a double delete causing undefined behavior.

You don't need to use a raw pointer. You can simply use a `std::vector` will handle the allocation of the elements as well as its destruction. That also means that you won't need to implement any other kinds of constructors or a destructor for `B` since `std::vector` handles copies and moves correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have all of them I show here only very simplified code to highlight a problem.